# Compiling C# with non-standard language features

Tags: c#, roslyn

I need to compile user-typed expressions into .NET assemblies that can be invoked. The expression language (inherited from version 1 of the application) is very limited and is *almost* valid C#, but it does have some unusual properties.

I want to switch to full C# in version 2, but I'm having trouble converting the idiosyncrasies into a compileable SyntaxTree using Roslyn. At the moment I'm trying to figure out how to get powers and factorials to compile, i.e.

```
double n = 1.5² / 0.9³ + 6!;
```

has to be converted into something like:

```
double n = Pow(1.5, 2) / Pow(0.9, 3) + Factorial(6);
```

However when I parse the original expression it all breaks down immediately at the `²` character:

```
public static void TestLanguageAdditions()
{
  const string code = "double n = 1.5² / 0.9³ + 6!;";

  var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
  var syntaxRoot = syntaxTree.GetRoot();

  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.AppendLine(code);
  sb.AppendLine();

  foreach (var node in syntaxRoot.DescendantNodes())
  {
    var span = node.FullSpan;
    var spanLine = 
      new string(' ', span.Start) + 
      new string('●', span.Length);

    spanLine = spanLine.PadRight(30);
    spanLine += ((CSharpSyntaxNode)node).Kind();

    sb.AppendLine(spanLine);
  }

  string report = sb.ToString();
  Console.Write(report);
}
```

Yields:

```
double n = 1.5² / 0.9³ + 6!;

●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●  FieldDeclaration
●●●●●●●●●●●●●●                VariableDeclaration
●●●●●●●                       PredefinedType
       ●●●●●●●                VariableDeclarator
         ●●●●●                EqualsValueClause
           ●●●                NumericLiteralExpression
```

I want to know if there's any way to coax Roslyn to parse the rest of the string as-is, or if not, what a good strategy would be for preparing the string. Obviously I could replace the `²` and `³` characters with some parseable placeholder, but not when those chars occur inside string or char literals.

----------------------------------- Edit -----------------------------------

Converting the illegal characters into block comments allows for parsing, although weirdly they appear as trivia after many of the nodes:

```
double n = 1.50/*²*/ / (0.90)/*³*/ + 6/*!*/;
●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●● CompilationUnit
●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●● FieldDeclaration
●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●· VariableDeclaration
······································●●●●●·  ˃ trivia: /*!*/
●●●●●●●····································· PredefinedType
·······●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●· VariableDeclarator
······································●●●●●·  ˃ trivia: /*!*/
·········●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●· EqualsValueClause
······································●●●●●·  ˃ trivia: /*!*/
···········●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●· AddExpression
······································●●●●●·  ˃ trivia: /*!*/
···········●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●········· DivideExpression
·····························●●●●●··········  ˃ trivia: /*³*/
···········●●●●●●●●●●······················· NumericLiteralExpression
···············●●●●●························  ˃ trivia: /*²*/
·······················●●●●●●●●●●●●········· ParenthesizedExpression
·····························●●●●●··········  ˃ trivia: /*³*/
························●●●●················ NumericLiteralExpression
·····································●●●●●●· NumericLiteralExpression
······································●●●●●·  ˃ trivia: /*!*/
```

Comment: I realise there are some issues with factorial, for example `...6!=x...` could be interpreted as a not-equals statement or as an attempted assignment statement. Since there exists an unambiguous way to enforce the factorial case; to wit `...(6!)=x...` I imagine it makes the most sense to always default to standard C# syntax in ambiguous cases, even if that results in erroneous code.

Comment: C#7 introduced digit separator inside number literals and it looks like `var t = 15_0_000`. So you can try to convert your expression to something like this: `1.5_2 / 0.9_3 + 6__0`, where one separate line would be degree and the two sequence lines – factorial. So Roslyn will think that it's a correct numeric literals and parse them. But in this case you should parse all these `NumericLiteralExpression` by hand as text to determine where was degree and factorial

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria yes, also replacing with single zeroes would allow for a syntax tree construction. But what if the power or factorial are associated with a parenthesised expression, or a variable? I’m thinking the only secure way is to replace ! with /*!*/

Comment: Yep, you can use /*!*/ to factorials and for degrees, but you should parse the trivia which appends to tokens by hand. I think that exists not only the one way, for example (I remember about variables) you can convert all degrees and factorials to parenthesized ternary operator, where `true` will indicate the degree and `false` – factorial. [Simple example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzsA0AmIGoA+ABADAAhQRgNwFgAoFAZiwCYMBhDAbyI0azJQBYMBZACgEo6GmTAG5gAThmABTALYAHDAF4M2AHQBWAoUFMA9DuXqAepX1c0KgJwYEGcmp6GyNrgDZrGEjwCEA7SPGSihhcwKIAroEA/BIy8iC2fKahERjR5lY2dhjxnu5cAGZgADYQURhuNmTx2DyaggC+RPVAA).

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you think it is a good idea to use a C# parser to parse something that isn't C#? Sounds like you'll have to write (or generate) your own parser for your own language.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten did you read the start of my question? Why would I go through a 10 year hellscape of developing my own language if I can leverage the flexibility, compatibility and performance of an existing one?

Comment: Because your language is not C#. You wouldn't try to parse - say - VB with a C# parser either, would you?